# « Être à disposition » ou « Être disponible »

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, noms

Sachant qu'« *Être à disposition* » signifie « *Être disponible* » dont l'origine est la suivante d'après [linternaute](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/18154/etre-a-disposition/):

> Raccourci de la locution "être mise à disposition" ("être
>   disponible"), cette expression tire sa signification du mot
>   "disposition" qui vient du verbe latin "disponere" ayant également
>   donné l'adjectif "disponible".

En réponse à la question *Seriez-vous intéressé pour en discuter ?*

Est-il plus correct de dire :

> Je reste disponible pour un éventuel échange.

Ou bien:

> Je suis à votre disposition pour un éventuel échange.

Comment: Selon moi, on peut être à disposition, mais pas disponible (pour l'instant) et inversement… Mais je n'ai pas encore trouvé de source pour appuyer cela, parmi celles à ma disponibilité…

Answer (score 2):

Comme Stéphane l'a écrit en commentaire, je vois une petite nuance entre les deux :

- **Je suis à votre disposition** signifie que l'on s'engage auprès d'une personne en particulier à prendre en compte et à répondre à ses demandes futures concernant ce dont on parle.
- **Je suis disponible** signifie que l'on peut traiter immédiatement la même demande, mais peut-être qu'on ne le sera bientôt plus si l'opportunité n'est pas saisie rapidement. **Je reste disponible** supprime le risque décrit précédemment. On peut cependant être disponible mais sans pour autant être à la disposition de quelqu'un en particulier, par exemple parce qu'on traite les demandes de plusieurs personnes à la fois.

Dans l'exemple cité, la formule la plus adaptée dans un contexte commercial, car elle s'adresse directement au client, est:

> Je suis à votre disposition pour un éventuel échange.

Answer (score 0):

Je crois la réponse dépende du contexte/registre.
Si nous souhaitions garder un registre soutenu, nous dirions :

> Je demeure à votre disposition pour un éventuel échange.
>
> Je me mets à votre disposition pour un éventuel échange.

En revanche,

> Je suis à votre disposition pour un éventuel échange.

me semble bizarre mais, étant non locuteur natif, je me trombe probablement

Sinon, nous pourrions dire tout simplement :

> Je reste disponible pour un éventuel échange.

Voir les exemples [ici](http://www.bdlp.org/fiche.asp?base=BE&no=2326&rubrique=) :

> Être à disposition de qqn. Le règlement du concours est à disposition
> des concurrents sur notre site. – Mettre à disposition de qqn. Nous
> mettons un consultant à disposition de votre entreprise. – Rester à
> disposition de qqn. Je reste à disposition de votre équipe si besoin
> en est. – Tenir à disposition de qqn. L'avocat tient à disposition du
> juge les pièces litigieuses. – Se trouver à disposition de qqn. Une
> ligne téléphonique particulière se trouve à disposition des clients
> mécontents.